# How to configure Play to generate a unique URL according to the asset content?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I would like to have all static assets (javascript, css, images) have this cache behavior:

1. Cache them "forever"
2. Their URL should be a unique URL generated from their content (e.g. MD5(content))
3. Whenever the asset content changes, the URL for the asset changes, so clients know to fetch a new version.
4. This should happen automagically without code changes.

Can I configure Play 2 to do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK *Play 2* automatically use caches for assets when using the `Assets` controller to generate *reverse routes* to your files.

From the book "Play for Scala":

> As well as reverse routing, another benefit of using the assets
>   controller is its built-in caching support, using an HTTP Entity Tag
>   (ETag). This allows a web client to make conditional HTTP requests for
>   a resource so that the server can tell the client it can use a cached
>   copy instead of returning a resource that hasn’t changed.
>
> [...]
>
> The ETag header value is a hash of the resource file’s name and
>   modification date. Don’t worry if you don’t know about hashes: all you
>   need to know is that if the file on the server is updated, with a new
>   version of a logo for example, this value will change. Once it has an
>   ETag value, a HTTP client can make a conditional request, which means
>   ‘only give me this resource if it hasn’t been modified since I got the
>   version with this ETag.’ To do this, the client includes the ETag
>   value in a request header

Comment: This is nice, although I ask specifically about filenames. Some applications (e.g. CDNs) might not work with ETAGs. In this article about CDN Sumo on Heroku, ETAGs are not mentioned - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn_sumo - it seems to work with unique URLs (`This way the asset is “fingerprinted” and if you ever change the file, the filename will change since it has a different “fingerprint”`)

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't answer... I still have no practical experience of Play, only learning right now. Good luck